# Why there is no sp2s hybridization in hydrocarbons?

Tags: organic-chemistry, hydrocarbons, hybridization, valence-bond-theory

If carbon's $\mathrm{sp^2}$ orbital is overlapped with hydrogen's $\mathrm{s},$ then why it is $\mathrm{sp^2}$ and why not $\mathrm{sp^2s}?$

Comment: Why it should be ?

Comment: Well, that's simply not a notation that exists.

Comment: You seem to have tried to combine the specification of two atomic orbitals to give a molecular bonding orbital. It doesn't work like that. For ethylene (see webpage) the two $\mathrm{sp^2}$ atomic orbitals of the carbon atoms overlap to give a C-C σ molecular bond. For each carbon hydrogen bond the overlap of the $\mathrm{sp^2}$ orbital of the carbon atom and the s orbital of the hydrogen atom give a C-H σ molecular bond.

Answer (score 5):

The sp notation for hybridised orbitals applies only to the orbitals of single atoms. All orbitals that are hybridised must be centred on the same nucleus.

Once you move to molecular orbitals, i.e. bonding *between* atoms, the sp notation no longer makes sense and is not used. Instead, localised bonds are typically referred to as σ, π, δ (depending on their symmetry with respect to rotation around the bond axis) while orbitals across the entire molecule are typically referred to by their symmetry descriptor (e.g. $\mathrm{e_g}$ orbitals in an octahedral adduct).

Comment: Might be a good place to point out that these names are also abbreviations of abbreviations: $\mathrm{sp}^h \equiv \mathrm{s}^\frac{1}{1+h}\mathrm{p}^\frac{h}{1+h}$.

Answer (score 2):

So you would like to hybridize $2s, 2p$ and $3s$ from the same atom, for example. Well ! Hybridization can only be done with orbitals having nearly the same energy. It is the case for $2s$ and $2p$. But it cannot be done with $1s$ and $2s$, or with $2s$ and $3s$. Their energies are too much different !

Comment: That is practically correct, but theoretically not. You can of course form a hybrid orbital from those components; physically it doesn't make any sense though. Since hybridisation is an entirely mathematical concept, it's still possible.